# Error #2044 Adobe flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, cross-domain, flex4

I have to display an image from an external URL but the Adobe flash debugger displays

> Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security
>   sandbox violation**:**
>   http://localhost:8080/folder1/folder2/media/swf_demo.swf cannot load
>   data from http://example.com/image.
>    A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded.

I have included a crossdomain.xml in my tomcat root server. Its contents are as follows:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?> 
    <cross-domain-policy> 
       <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
       <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
       <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
       <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"/>
    </cross-domain-policy>
```

My mxml code of displaying the image is as follows:

```
<mx:Canvas>
   <controls:MultiSourceImage id="Icon" width="19" height="19" x="3" y="3" trustContent="true"/>
   <mx:Image id="Badge" width="11" height="11"/>  
</mx:Canvas>
```

The image is not getting displayed. 
Am I missing something? Or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: What are you doing? You reversed a perfectly good edit (by user : **Null**) and made it into messy code? Only testable code should be put in the grey box not explanations... Anyways, the **crossdomain.xml** must exist at root of **example.com** server itself, to allow outside apps (ie: yours) to load its image data. Crossdomain is for content protection.

Comment: Also using [`Security.loadPolicyFile()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile()) and [`Security.allowDomain("*")`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#allowDomain())might help